# Text gets out from its container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cannot figure out why the whole fonts in the modern browsers don't fit its corresponding width? So, here we can see a brilliant example, where `84` goes out of its width borders... Why?

Example via devtools screenshot:[image]

By the code:

```css
.test {
  color: #fff;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 8px;
      line-height: 2;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: right;
      text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<span class="test">84</span>
```

Comment: do you really need text to be that small?

Comment: @ishidex2 yes, sure. Otherwise, I would not post this question.

Comment: shadow is not part of the width calculation. you can hide it with overflow: hidden or add padding depending on the size of your shadow.

Answer (score 3):

The text itself (in white) stays inside of the span. The text-shadow you are applying is not taken into consideration for layouting since it is considered a purely aesthetic element.

If you want to prevent the text shadow from leaving the span, you can set `overflow: hidden`:

```css
.test {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  text-shadow: -10px -10px 0 #000, 10px -1px 0 #000, -10px 10px 0 #000, 10px 10px 0 #000;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<span class="test">84</span>
```

And if you want to the box to expand to cover the shadow, you can add some padding as needed:

```css
.test {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  text-shadow: -10px -10px 0 #000, 10px -1px 0 #000, -10px 10px 0 #000, 10px 10px 0 #000;
  background: red;
  padding: 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<span class="test">84</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set shadow width to half of pixel (`0.5px`)

```css
.test {
  color: #fff;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 8px;
      line-height: 2;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: right;
      text-shadow: -0.5px -0.5px 0 #000, 0.5px -0.5px 0 #000, -0.5px 0.5px 0 #000, 0.5px 0.5px 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<span class="test">84</span>
```